Identify X-files like tv show
This has being bothering me for weeks, it was a tv show similar to X-files in the meaning of paranormal events episode by episode to be investigated but it was in a more modern environment, i remember the main character suffered from time skip without having control of it or something at some point in the series. I watched it a few years (like I cannot recall exactly but it was 5+ years ago) on a Italian channel but I am sure it was not an italian series.
I'll try to describe a episode but the details might be wrong since, you know time passes and memories get unclear. 
I remember this particular episode of case in which many time-space anomalies were happening and in the end they discovered they were coming from a house in which a man made a machine to stop time to keep his dying wife alive. 
Again, I do not remember a lot about it and that is what is bothering me. After all this might even be X-files itself and I am being confused or something. 
If don't know names of characters/actors.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

You might be looking for Fringe (2008-2013), which bears a lot of semblance to X-Files.
The episode you describe could be Season 4, Episode 6: And Those We Left Behind, first aired November 2011. From the Wikipedia plot summary:

[...] One unfortunate FBI agent is vaporized while approaching a suburban home, and Walter recognizes that a time bubble is surrounding the home. Isolating the extent of the time bubble, they find the home belongs to a couple, Raymond (Stephen Root) and Kate (Romy Rosemont) Green; Kate was a distinguished professor in physics at a nearby university until three years ago when she was diagnosed with early-onset Alzheimer's disease. Walter devises a portable Faraday cage that Peter offers to wear to enter the time bubble safely. Inside, he finds that Raymond, a skilled electrical engineer, used Kate's research to construct a giant machine in the basement of their house that creates a temporary time bubble. Raymond has used the machine to revert their home to the state four years prior, before Kate fully suffered from rapid deterioration of Alzheimer's, and has been convincing her younger version to complete her research to allow him to stabilize the time bubble permanently. Raymond notes that he has successfully gotten the machine to work only in the last few days. [...]

